# overloading the insertion operator questions, theoretical

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

When overloading the insertion operator (operator<<) in order to insert an object (say a shae) into an output stream (file or console), we had to implement it as a global function. why was this?
Could someone show me an example prototype for this function for inserting a shape into an ostream object?
How is this different than having this operator as a member of our class(like a shape)?

Comment: look under **Bitshift Operators (used for Stream I/O)** in the first answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34954015/434551

Comment: This is already answered in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421729#4421729) to the operator overloading FAQ.